# Laravel Resource temporarily unavailable cannot unset

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, upload

Using Laravel I want to delete my file use `unset` using `ajax` but Laravel gives me ab error like this:

> unlink(...) Resource temporarily unavailable

Here is my code , but it does work if I waited like 10 seconds the code returns succesfully and not with an error,

```
  //This my code for delete
  $listening = Listening::find($id);
  if ($listening->audio !== $request->audio) {
    unlink(public_path('listening/admin/'.$listening->audio));
  }
```

Comment: Formatting needed some structure

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly without a lot more information, but the error is pretty helpful: you most likely have a handle open to the file that you are trying to delete.  Or, perhaps if it is a new file, it may not have been created by the time the async (AJAX) request comes through to delete it.

It looks like you are performing some action on this file.  If it is an audio file and your user is actually listening to it while you try to delete it, add a line in there to disengage the user from the file, and then delete.

If it is just a transmission timing error, add a buffer or delay between AJAX and the delete code.